# VSTS: how to require a branch to be up to date before merging (doing pull request) from that branch?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In [Github](https://github.community/t/best-practices-for-protected-branches/10204), it's possible to require a branch to be up to date before one can merge it:  see https://github.community/t/best-practices-for-protected-branches/10204

> By also enabling Require branches to be up to date before merging you
> can make sure that checks are ran against the latest state of the
> target branch

How can one enforce this in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> VSTS: how to require a branch to be up to date before merging (doing pull request) from that branch?

I once had the same request as you, but after a period of research and test, I found that this is a unique feature of github. Azure devops **does not** have the similar feature of `Require branches to be up to date before merging` in github:

[image]

Just as you said, the developers or requesters could resolve the conflict before completing the PR, However, the Reviewers will still receive these conflicting PRs. Obviously this is an interruption for reviewers.

I thought I was the only one with a special request before. Since we have the same request now, I add this request for this feature on the UserVoice site, which is main forum for product suggestions:

[Azure devops support the feature "Require branches to be up to date before merging"](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1196970/azure-devops-support-the-feature-require-branches.html)

You could vote it up and add your comment for free.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that the build in the PR will always run against the latest target branch you need to configure the "Build expiration" to "Immediately when 'branch name' is updated".

[image]

See the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation):

> **Immediately when branch name is updated:** This option sets the build
> policy status in a pull request to failed when the protected branch is
> updated. Requeue a build to refresh the build status. This setting
> ensures that the changes in pull requests build successfully even as
> the protected branch changes. This option is best for teams that have
> important branches with a lower volume of changes. Teams working in
> busy development branches may find it disruptive to wait for a build
> to complete every time the protected branch is updated.

Comment: The problem we want to solve is people doing pull requests without first updating from the main, thus leaving the maintainer of main to do all the conflict resolution. If the dev is forced to pull from main to his branch to make sure his branch is up to date before doing a PR to main from his branch, he will have to edit the conflicts himself.  i.e. nothing to do with any build.  Unless there is some other rule that will prevent the branch from merging with main if the build policy status is false, this won't stop PRs being made from an outdated branch.

Comment: Oh ok, I missed that in GitHub it requires the pr branch to do the merge from the target (main). but, in Azure DevOps, if there are conflicts you can't complete the merge, so the pr requester has to solve the conflicts himself.

Comment: The PR requester can resolve the conflicts, but he doesn't have to.  He can leave it up to anyone else that has rights to approve the PR. The PR will sit there unapproved as long as there are conflicts. We want to make it so the PR requester has to resolve the conflicts always.

Comment: In GitHub also, there is only "a message will appear to indicate that those changes need to be merged upstream into the pull request branch before merging", the PR request can "listen" to the message or not, the PR could be also sitting there unapproved as long as there are conflicts. what is the difference?

Comment: If in GitHub you have enabled strict branch protection,  then "the branch must be up to date before merging".  So the dev will have to make sure his branch is up to date, so the conflicts will show up on his branch first.  Maybe there is nothing forcing him to resolve the conflicts on his own branch before doing a PR to main. I haven't checked what the messages in Github are but it would probably be "branch requires update" rather than "branch requires update and here are some conflicts to edit because of that"